# The vertices of each of these two different parabolas, each with different lower order 't' terms, trace each other's graphs for all times 't', why?

Tags: polynomials, conic-sections

https://www.desmos.com/calculator/z2yi8pjyej

In this graph, there are two parabolas -- one is $f(x) = x^2 + tx + t$, while the other is $g(x) = -x^2 + t$.

As long as the '$x^2$' terms are of opposite sign and have the same coefficient; and all of the '$t$' terms in both equations share the same sign; and the lowest order '$t$' terms in each equation share the same coefficient, the vertex of each parabola will seem to (I do not attempt to prove this) trace the other parabola's graph for all times '$t$'.

So, in general, this seems to remain true so long as the equations take the forms: 
$f(x) = \pm(Cx^2+Dtx+Ft+G)$, and $g(x) = \mp(Cx^2-Ft-G)$, where '$C$', '$D$', '$F$', and '$G$', are all arbitrary, non-zero (with the exception of '$G$'), real constants, that have the same value in both equations in which they appear (with the exception of '$D$', which is only found in $f(x)$.)

Is there a simple, nontrivial explanation for why this occurs?

<sub>(I tried to find some analogous phenomenon in higher order equations, but I wasn't successful, so while this might generalize to polynomial functions of all orders, I didn't figure out if, nor how, it might.)</sub>

Comment: Use LaTeX please.

Comment: The animation is interesting, and I believe I understand what you mean, but it's not really appropriate to say that each vertex "traces" the other parabola for all times $t$. (As $t$ changes, the parabolas move, so neither is a fixed path being "traced".) As for what's happening: You have congruent parabolas opening in opposite directions. Since the equations have the same constant term (relative to $x$), the curves cross on the $y$-axis. The common point there is the vertex of your $g$-parabola; a simple symmetry argument shows that the curves must also cross at the $f$-parabola's vertex.